# C++ Reading text file as binary and show it in console

Tags: c++, windows, binary, console

I try to read one text file as binary and then render it in console-app.
I've got the next result: http://pastebin.com/gubYpAVZ

I'm questioning: "Why I have got such symbols, that I don't have in the text file?" , if I open it in notepad - I shall see only "Hello World!" and no more... What are other symbols???

Here is code:

```
ifstream in("C:\\dev\\1.txt", ios::in | ios::binary);    
list<int> mylist1;
list<int>::iterator it;


while(!in.eof())
{
    mylist1.push_back(in.get());
};

for(it = mylist1.begin(); it != mylist1.end(); it++)
{
    cout << *it << " -> " << (char)*it << endl;
};


in.close();
```

Best Regards,

Comment: oops... haven't learned hot to format text yet, where list is, the generic type is: list < int >

Comment: just indent the code with four spaces

Comment: You seem to be slightly confused about the whole thing. The first for-loop looks quite weird, why do you even have it?

Comment: yeah, it was really weird... it's just code from past ( haven't erased it ), thanks for the finding such thing

Comment: What does your input text file look like? Are the indivdual characters 4-bytes (i.e. UTF-32 text file)?

Comment: the last result from updated code above is here: http://pastebin.com/gubYpAVZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility might be that the file contains Unicode characters, which might have multiple bytes per character.  And some of those character values at the beginning look like they are part of a [BOM (byte order mark)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).  In particular, 239, 187, 191 (0xef, 0xbb, 0xbf) seem to indicate some UTF-8 data.

Comment: @AndreasMagnusson:  I'm probably missing the obvious ... but I'm not sure what you are referring to.  The looping is definitely all messed up (it prints the entire set of characters for every character read ... but that it still seems to be picking up a BOM).

Comment: Have changed code, it works well! Thanks (the updated version ), but I have the first three symbols:
239 -> я
187 -> ╗
191 -> ┐

Comment: @MarkWilkins: Yep, you're right. I assumed the op wanted to know why his output was so messed up and not just printing `Hello World!` But the *weird* characters he's seeing is most likely a BOM, especially since he used notepad to create the file.

Comment: @user1131997:  Those are the byte order marks indicating the file is UTF-8.  If all the character values are less than integer value 127, they will only take a single byte in UTF-8.  If you created the file with notepad, you can save it as ANSI (there should be an Encoding option in the save as dialog).